# Armv7 + Arm64 fat build is incompatible with iPhone 4s

Tags: iphone, xamarin, 64-bit

My Unified API Xamarin app can be built in both Armv7 and Armv7+Arm64 thin and fat build architectures.
When I build it in Armv7 architecture I can deploy and run it on an iPhone4s. When I build it in Armv7+Arm64 architecture(s) I can deploy and run it on iPhone5 and above.
Why can't I deploy Armv7+Arm64 build to iPhone 4s?

This is the error I get:

Installing application bundle
writeDictToFile:1258 ==== Successfully wrote Manifest cache to /var/folders/9y/yvyksjvd38g_gnkndcw4y_100000gn/T/Xamarin.iOS_InstallShadowPath/d2d4e62f663137bab4687ec28f35467b/aead04c30517c7b5a662da00c34e58e38ac78222/ManifestCache.plist
error MT1006: Could not install the application '/Users/noammeirofek/RoX/bin/RumbleTouch.app' on the device Adi’s iPhone: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle returned: 0xe8000087 (kAMDIncorrectArchitectureError).
The application was terminated by a signal: SIGHUP

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error (which led me to your question), but under different circumstances - so I'm sorry but I cannot explain why `ARMv7+ARM64` did not work for you when just `ARMv7` did.

Are you sure you were deploying to an iPhone4s and not an iPhone5?

I am deploying to an iPad 3 and my architecture settings were `ARMv7s + ARM64`. I got the same error in your writeup. When I chose instead `ARMv7 + ARM64`, the app deployed.

Per Xamarin Studio (options, iOS Build, Advanced):

> ARMv7s is the latest architecture supported only by the new A6 processor included in the iPhone5

You might want to choose `ARMv7 + ARMv7s + ARM64` in the dropdown option called `Supported architectures`on the `Advanced` tab

According to this [list of iOS devices](https://www.innerfence.com/howto/apple-ios-devices-dates-versions-instruction-sets), your original selection *should* have worked, because the iPhone4s has an ARMv7

I experimented with my app on an iPhone4 (I don't have an iPhone4s) and the deploy worked with ARMv7+ARM64 (your original setting), and did *not* work for ARMv7s+ARM64 (as expected) and *did work* with the all-inclusive ARMv7+ARMv7s+ARM64

I am also using a Unified 64bit API, Xamarin Studio, XCode 7 and my iPad has iOS 9.0 installed.